# how to avoid same input id value in c++

Tags: c++, input, linked-list

how to avoid double id in linked listed, example, i have id, name, gol, so firtst, i input id= 12, name=jon gol=A, when i input again. id=12, its show message "Id cant be same". input again can you help

this is my code for insert linked list first node,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

struct node {
    int id;
    char name[20], gol;

    node *next;
};

node *head = nullptr;
node *tail = nullptr;

void tambah_awal_list() {
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char gol;
    
    node *baru = new node;
    baru->id=head->id;
    std::cout << "Id : ";
    std::cin >> baru->id;
    if (head->id == baru->id){
        std::cout << "Id cant be same"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << "Name : ";
    std::cin >> baru->name;

    std::cout << "Blood type (A/B/O) : ";
    std::cin >> baru->gol;


    if(head == nullptr) {
        head = baru;
        head->next = nullptr;
        tail = head;
    } else {
        baru->next = head;
        head = baru;
    }
}
```

what should i change?

Comment: Have a `std::unordered_set<int> usedId` to save your `id`s. You may lookup by `usedId.count(id) != 0` to know whether it's used. Don't forget to erase the id when a node is removed.

Comment: how can i implemented, i still dont understand.

Comment: Don't edit a question in such a way that it makes the answers obsolete.

Comment: If you want to update the question, leave your original code at first and put your modified code later.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the spec and performance requirements.

1. If `id` could be decided by code instead of user input, then you just need to have an global counter increment every time a node is created.
   You have to handle it carefully under multi-threading cases or very large number when number of nodes is out of range of `int`.

```
// Global variable or class member
int g_nextID = 0;
int generateID(){return ++g_nextID;}

void generate(){
    node* n = new node();
    n->id = generateID();
    // ... 
}
```

2. Use [`std::unordered_set<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) which takes O(1) time and O(N) space.

```
// A global variable or class member
std::unordered_set<int> g_used;
node *head = nullptr;
node *tail = nullptr;

void generate(){
    // Inside the function
    int id;
    // Get user input into id
    // ...

    // Checking if used
    if(g_used.find(id) == g_used.end()){
        // Create the node
        // ...

        g_used.insert(id); // Save it
    }else{
        // Error handling.
    }
}

void removeNode(int id){
    // Remove it from list
    // ...

    // Remove it from set
    g_used.erase(id);
}
```

3. Lookup the nodes, but it takes O(N) times.

Comment: i used number 2 but, but when i  input id for the first time, it gives me else condition"id cant be same", it should success. can you help Id https://pastebin.com/xuTHsrK2

Comment: Sounds like you want to ask a new question. Be a few hours before you can do that, so I recommend you spend the time researching the problem and debugging.

Comment: @Xianying, I wrote the logic in the wrong way, sorry. I just fixed it.

Comment: @Xianying, also you have to move `g_used` out of `tambah_awal_list()`, because `g_used` must exist longer than `tambah_awal_list()`. You may move `g_used` aside to `head` and `tail`.

Comment: solved. thank mate. glad you help me.